# Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

To create a 3d scatterplot, I copied and pasted the code from p.132 of the manual http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel={$z$},
title=A Scatter Plot Example,
]
\addplot3+ [only marks]
    table {plotdata/TestTable.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and my TestTable.dat file is

```
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   2   1
```

I get the error: "Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'plotdata/TestTable.dat' inrefer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). table {plotdata/TestTable.dat};"

My TestTable.dat is saved as a .dat file and is in the same folder as the tex file. Can someone explain the error, even though I followed the manual?

Comment: You have written that the DAT file is in the same folder as the TEX file, but in the `\addplot` command you stated that the file is in the subfolder "plotdata". So either move the file to that subfolder or replace `plotdata/TestTable.dat` with just `TestTable.dat`.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?